# Material-ui ListItem style override @media

Tags: css, material-ui

I need to change style of `ListItem` in material-ui.

I have list of my elements that, after filling, I am returning to a `Popover`.

```
elms.push(<ListItem key={i} primaryText={obj[i].title} onTouchTap={this.addGeotag.bind(this, obj[i])}/>)
```

If I simply add `style={{line-height:"5"}}` to `ListItem` everything works fine.

But I need to make use of `@media max-width: ...`. Since I will have a few options there. ex. `850px, 1200px, ...`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.listenOnResize);
},

componentDidUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.listenOnResize);
},

listenOnResize(event) {
    // Do calculations here
    // Save in state what size prop you want for your component
},
```